# Intersection of Probabilities and Bayes Theorem

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

It is known that 70% of women and 60% of men have voted in a poll, in a village where 500
women and 400 men live. If only 80% of the inhabitants tells the truth, what is the probability that a person who says "I did vote" is telling the truth?

I've broken this problem down into the events:

V = The person voted

T = The person tells the truth

I know as well that I'm looking for $P(T|V)$. I know in order to calculate this, by Bayes Theorem, I need to calculate $P(V|T)$.

I have that $P(V) = \frac{59}{90}$ and $P(T) = \frac{8}{10}$. My problem is that I don't know that I have enough information to calculate $P(V \cap T)$ to be able to continue and get a concrete probability for $P(T|V)$.

Answer (score 2):

$350+240=590$ of $500+400=900$ voted. $472$ of those who voted would say they voted while $62$ of those who didn't vote would say they voted. Thus, $\frac{472}{472+62}=\frac{236}{267}$ of those who said they voted would actually have voted.

Comment: But with ypur approach you are stating that telling the truth is independent of voting

Comment: It is stated that $80\%$ of the inhabitants tell the truth. That sounds as if sex and whether they voted is irrelevant. If there were more information given to the contrary, we could use it.

Answer (score 2):

You are thinking it the wrong way:

The person who said I did vote has either vote and telling the truth or not voted and lying.

So:

let B: the person says that voted

let T: the person is telling the truth

let V: the person voted

$P(B) = P(V \cap T) + P(notV \cap notT)$

so B: voted and tells the truth plus not voted and lie

$P(T|B) = \frac{P(T \cap B)}{P(B)}$

$P(T|B) = \frac{P(T \cap V)}{P(V \cap T) + P(notV \cap notT)}$

$P(V) = \frac{0.7 \times 500 +0.6 \times 400}{900} = 590/900$

$P(T) = 0.8 $

so

$P(T|B) = \frac{\frac{590}{900}\times 0.8}{\frac{590}{900}\times 0.8 + (1-\frac{590}{900}) \times 0.2}$

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the tree diagram:

$\hspace{2cm}$[image]

The required probability is:
$$\frac{\text{n(people who claim to have voted and had voted indeed)}}{\text{n(people who claim to have voted, but they may or may not have voted)}}=\\
\frac{WVT+MVT}{(WVT+MVT)+(WN'L+MV'L)}=\\
\frac{500\cdot 0.7\cdot 0.8+400\cdot 0.6\cdot 0.8}{(500\cdot 0.7\cdot 0.8+400\cdot 0.6\cdot 0.8)+(500\cdot 0.3\cdot 0.2+400\cdot 0.4\cdot 0.2)}=\\
\frac{472}{472+62}=\frac{236}{267}\approx 0.88.$$
Note:

1) WVT - women voted and telling truth (they did vote);

2) WV'L - women did not vote, but lying (they said they had voted);

3) MVT - men voted and telling truth (they did vote);

4) MV'L - men did not vote, but lying (they said they had voted).